# How to change leaf icon in TreeGrid

Tags: javascript, dojo, treegrid

How can I set an icon for some column in dojox.grid.TreeGrid / LazyTreeGrid ?

In dijit.Tree I can overload getIconClass method to acomplish this.

Comment: A formatter function(I don't know if TreeGrid supports it) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS for that:

```css
.dojoxGridCell[role="gridcell"][idx="3"]:before
{
  content: url(icon.png);
}
```

This will display `icon.png` in grid cells (indicated by class `dojoxGridCell` and attribute `role="gridcell"`) in column with the index 3.

This is using generated content so you might want to consult the [support matrix](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3abefore). If you need to support IE6/IE7 then you will need a fallback solution, all other browsers will do fine.